# I'm creating a table in in which the data is being gotten from a JSON file. this is the code

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
var myObj, i, t = document.querySelector("#data_table");

myObj = {
name: "John",
age: 30,
cars: [
{name: "Ford", models: ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]},
{name: "BMW", models: ["320", "X3", "X5"]},
{name: "Fiat", models: ["500", "Panda"]}
]

};

for (i in myObj.cars) {
var _row = t.insertRow(-1);


var c = _row.insertCell(-1);
c.innerHTML = myObj.cars[i].name;
c.style.fontWeight = "bolder";

for (var j = 0; j < myObj.cars[i].models.length; j++) {
var _c = _row.insertCell(-1);
_c.innerHTML = myObj.cars[i].models[j];
}
}
```

my problem now is the name of the cars are appear on in a single column instead of a row (e.g they should be the table header for each column). but i havent been able to figure it out. your help would be appreciated.

This is the html

```
<table width='100%' id='data_table' class="table table-condensed table-hover">
<caption> VEHICLE DATA </caption>

</table>
```

A link of what it looks like now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1YAz.png)

But this is what i want it to look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2B3z.png)

Comment: Please provide sample of expected html structure as per [mcve]

Comment: I just updated it with links to what the html structure looks like and what i want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this it would work.[image]

```
var myObj, i, t = document.querySelector("#data_table");

myObj = {
    name: "John",
    age: 30,
    cars: [{
            name: "Ford",
            models: ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]
        },
        {
            name: "BMW",
            models: ["320", "X3", "X5"]
        },
        {
            name: "Fiat",
            models: ["500", "Panda"]
        }
    ]

};

//Determine the max rows to draw (except the header) in the table
var rowCount = 0;
for (i in myObj.cars) {
    if (myObj.cars[i].models.length > rowCount) {
        rowCount = myObj.cars[i].models.length;
    }
}
//Add header row
var headerRow = t.insertRow(-1);
for (i in myObj.cars) {
    var c = headerRow.insertCell(-1);
    c.innerHTML = myObj.cars[i].name;
    c.style.fontWeight = "bolder";
}

//Add details rows and cells
for (var j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
    var _row = t.insertRow(-1);

    //Add cells for each row
    for (i in myObj.cars) {
        var _c = _row.insertCell(i);
        if (myObj.cars[i].models[j]) {
            _c.innerHTML = myObj.cars[i].models[j];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hi @seyi do you try the answer ? can you check it if right

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tested this and it works.  It will first add the names as the top row, then it will insert rows as needed and add the car types to the appropriate columns

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<table width="100%" id="data_table" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
<caption> VEHICLE DATA </caption>

</table>
</script>
<script>

var myObj, i, t = document.querySelector("#data_table");

myObj = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30,
  cars: [
   {name: "Ford", models: ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]},
   {name: "BMW", models: ["320", "X3", "X5"]},
   {name: "Fiat", models: ["500", "Panda"]}
  ]
};

var _row1 = t.insertRow(-1);
for (i in myObj.cars) {
  var c = _row1.insertCell(-1);
  c.innerHTML = myObj.cars[i].name;
  c.style.fontWeight = "bolder";
}

var topcount = 0;
for (i=0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {

  for (var j = 0; j < myObj.cars[i].models.length; j++) {
    if (topcount <= j) {
      var _row = t.insertRow(-1);
      topcount++;
      if(i > 0){
        for( var k = 0; k < i; k++){
          var _c = _row.insertCell(-1);
        }
      }
    } else {
      _row = t.rows[j+1];
    }
    var _c = _row.insertCell(-1);
    _c.innerHTML = myObj.cars[i].models[j];
  }

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```